# list view update with time

Tags: java, android, listview

I am writing a world clock application in which I am using a custom list view and adapter. I show a list of cities and their times. The problem is I want to keep updating the time for each city shown in the view, as the seconds pass. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the adapter set up for the listview, you can update the adapter data set and notify the view of changes, see this api: [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29). but since it is updating every sec. I am not sure this method is efficient in terms of performance.

Comment: Performance would be OK,  because list will pass only visible entries to update.

Comment: As long as your adapter is set up efficiently this should be fine. You are, after all, changing every on-screen element and ListView has a shortcut layout path that it uses when adapters change view contents vs. when the views change contents outside of an adapter's getView. Make sure you aren't using wrap_content for the ListView's height.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track on views used to display individual times would not help, as views are
reused - your best bet is to notify list that dataset is changed,  and update individual views.   If you take care and reuse city views, amount of view updates will be low.